# Can't put Double number in BigDecimal variable

Tags: java, double, classcastexception, bigdecimal, jspinner

I'm using a Double variable which holds the Item price. That variable is stored in postgresql database under a column of money type. I use  setBigDecimal(position,value) SQL function.In other part, i'm using a JSpinner as input.

```
Double current = 0.0;
Double min = (double) Integer.MIN_VALUE;
Double max = (double) Integer.MAX_VALUE;
Double step = 0.1;

JSpinner priceSpinner = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(current, min, max, step));
```

When the user clicks on a button, I get the value entred by the user and put it in the database via SQL query.

```
 insertStmt.setBigDecimal(position,BigDecimal.valueOf((double) priceSpinner.getValue()));
```

But, i got this little error,

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
```

Comment: JSpinner.getValue() returns an object, which you try to cast to Double (Which does not seem to be possible as it's current class is BigDecimal) as You require BigDecimal, try setBigDecimal(position,(BigDecimal) priceSpinner.getValue());

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace - which line of your code is actually causing the exception?

Comment: Important note: try not to instantiate BigDecimal objects with a double parameter. Always pass a String argument. There's a good piece on this, but I can't find the link for the life of me.

Comment: when the priceSpinner is not filled (default value is zero) i got this error Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to java.lang.Double

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This program illustrates conversion in both directions between Double and BigDecimal:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Double d1 = 1.3;
    BigDecimal bd1 = BigDecimal.valueOf(d1.doubleValue());
    Double d2 = bd1.doubleValue();
    System.out.println(d2);
  }
}
```

Note that the conversion to Double may not be exact.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously `priceSpinner.getValue()` returns `BigDecimal` and you're trying to convert it to `double` and then back to `BigDecimal`.

Why don't you just do?

```
insertStmt.setBigDecimal(position, (BigDecimal) priceSpinner.getValue());
```

Comment: incompatible type object cannot be converted to bigdecimal

Comment: priceSpinner.getValue() returns an Object not BigDecimal

Comment: With a model constructed from Doubles the spinner will be returning a Double.

Comment: Yes, but there's still a need of explicit cast, because the compiler won't be aware of how the spinner is constructed.

Comment: Yes, but you can't cast Double to BigDecimal - did you actually try your code?

Comment: Yes, i can't cast Double to BigDecimal. I got this error : Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to java.lang.Double

Comment: Yeah, I don't see how the line identified in the question could generate the error given, thus the full stacktrace is needed.

Comment: Yes it is in this same line

Comment: I just simulate the problem, because it's an inventory application where i have form to get product information, when the user click O.K button i send those informations to my database.